# Online Client-to-Client Payments

Tags: e-commerce, payment

Im developing a website which allows clients to accept payments from other clients with the website taking a small cut of the transfer, similar to the way ebay works. My question is what would you reccommend i use for providing the bank transaction?

Ive got limited experience of online payment technology so i have no idea what would be best. My initial thought was to use paypal but (correct me if im wrong) paypal doesnt seem to provide this functionality.

An idea which i want to avoid is having the transaction go through my own acount i.e. the buyer sends me money which gets sent straight to the seller. This because if - after the transaction - the buyer opens a dispute then the dispute will be with my account rather than directly the seller (obviously the percentage taken by the website will be part of the dispute).

My main concerns are with non-paying clients or disputes so i need a way of being notified that a transaction has taken place for definite.

If anyone has any advice/experience of this or can point me in the right direction it will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Look into [Paypal Adaptive Payments](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APIntro) and [Amazon Payment](https://payments.amazon.com/sdui/sdui/index.htm)s. They both allow for payments to be sent to two parties.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the adaptive payments is exactly what im looking for, not sure how i missed it :)

Answer (score 0):

BancBox might be what you're looking for

Comment: Are you associated with BancBox? If so, please state that you are. Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/55914/169404